# asp.net core api dosent take resource as it needs

Tags: api, iis, asp.net-core, response

I have web api that in normal condition has 100 concurrent requests . in this condition every things  its normal and service response quickly .

but when the request go highs like 1000 concurrent request the service dosent respond .

the cpu usage its almost 60 percent and memory almost 70 percent.

by the way the os its windows server and revers proxy its iis .

the queue length its 2000 .

is there any thing that i should change the config or check it ?

tip : most of methods are using redis cache in another server . the service just read from cache and response to user . but when request grow these methods are too low .

Comment: Did you run any profiling to see into CPU usage and memory usage? Without such data, merely talking won't give you a solution.

Comment: Take a look at [MiniProfiler for .NET](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/).  Are your actions async?